# App Submission Error - Invalid binary - Invalid Code Signing Error

Tags: binary, signing, submission

Invalid Code Signing Entitlements - Your application bundle's signature contains ubiquity code signing entitlements that are not supported.

Specifically, value "( X49XXXS5Q.* )" for key "com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers" in is not supported.

The key happens to be my distribution id.

Answer (score 27):

Yes that is the correct answer! 
steps to correct:

Find you app id in the portal -
dis-able the iCloud.
Create a new provisioning profile
download it 
delete the prior profile 
replace it with the new one
re-compile and submit.

Answer (score 14):

Disable iCloud in the Provisioning Portal and generate a new "distribution" Provisioning Profile before submitting it again to Apple.

Comment: how can I disable the iCloud in the provisioning portal? I just spent half an hour looking for a switch :(

Comment: Go to Apple's Provisioning Portal -> App IDs -> Click "Configure" on your App ID - there should be a checkbox. Apparently, the checkbox is gone now, they are probably working on it as iCloud is enabled by default now.

Comment: yeah, it's gone now... but I just discovered, that redownloading a brand new provisioning profile from the portal helps - apple seems to have removed the offending entitlement

Comment: This is quite annoying and it is stopping us from submitting the new update for our app. Any ideas how to disable the icloud function in the provisioning profile?

Comment: This is the correct answer and could use a "correct" thingy. At least worked for me.

Comment: thanks for the answer, Badcat. that nailed it.
and thanks for adding yet another obscure roadblock to the already insanely opaque app-submission process, Apple.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you have a wildcard app id set for your application. This is not allowed for distribution of applications. You should set your application to a dedicated app id like:

```
X49XXXS5Q.this.is.my.app
```

instead of

```
X49XXXS5Q.*
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Where do I set this?

Comment: In the provisioning portal you have to create a fixed app id, then you have to set this app id in XCode in the project settings.

Comment: I created a fixed app id. And I am using it in the project setting.

Comment: It went through. The issue was we enabled icloud option in the app id. I removed that, it worked.

Comment: I specifically logged in to upvote user667673's answer. Thank you my anonymous friend!